# How to make slider like google map location info in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, slider, bottom-sheet

I need help from your side.
Actually, I am making a demo app as a beginner, I want this kind of bar/container as in the first image. However, this would be called from the button and will open at highlighted area (as described in Second Image). I don't know how to to. Please, let me know and learn.

[1st Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSNEA.png)
[2nd Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8syx.png)

Comment: if the ans hels u  upv2 the answer bro

Comment: I likd ur 2 qstns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Use [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)

```
carousel_slider: ^4.1.1

import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

class CarouselDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  CarouselController buttonCarouselController = CarouselController();

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      CarouselSlider(
        items: child,
        carouselController: buttonCarouselController,
        options: CarouselOptions(
          autoPlay: false,
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          viewportFraction: 0.9,
          aspectRatio: 2.0,
          initialPage: 2,
        ),
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => buttonCarouselController.nextPage(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear),
        child: Text('→'),
      )
    ]
  );
}
```