# How to solve the grid view problem in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-test, flutter-gridview

I have a problem of grid view. I add lists as described in 1st screenshot, then the same list will be updated on the another page (as per second screenshot). However, as you can see overflow error, that is happening and I can not solve that. So, can you guys explain how to increase it's height as I add element in the lists. Hope, it is clear.

[1st image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbkB6.png)
[2nd image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8z8c.png)

Here is a Code:

```
Consumer<HomeProvider>(
                  builder: (context, provider, child) => GridView.builder(
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: provider.allData.length,
                      gridDelegate:
                          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: provider.isPress ? 2 : 1,
                          childAspectRatio: 1.4
                        
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                        return provider.allData[index];
                      }))
```

Comment: It is not having enough room on grid

Comment: Don't ask the same question multiple times!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make slider like google map location info in flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73206414/how-to-make-slider-like-google-map-location-info-in-flutter-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use **flutter_staggered_grid_view #** package

like this,

```
StaggeredGrid.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 12,
                children: [ 'your data'  ]
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

GridView `crossAxisCount` is not having enough room on gridItem. You can change `crossAxisCount`  by increasing height.

```dart
 childAspectRatio: width/height
```

Decrease `childAspectRatio` value like .6 or less

Comment: If you are looking for 1st ss view, you dont need to use GridView , check [ReorderableListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
   const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                                        crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                                        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                                        mainAxisExtent:
                                            110,  
                                      )
```

**Try setting mainAxisextent to something more and it will increase the hieght of that current grid element**

Answer (score 0):

Just use  `flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2`

```
StaggeredGrid.count(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  mainAxisSpacing: 4,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4,
  children: const [
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 2,
      mainAxisCellCount: 2,
      child: Tile(index: 0),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 2,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Tile(index: 1),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 1,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Tile(index: 2),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 1,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Tile(index: 3),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 4,
      mainAxisCellCount: 2,
      child: Tile(index: 4),
    ),
  ],
);
```